# Communicating from Service to Activity via Bind?

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, bind

I want to contact my Activity via my Service hopefully through Bind. I already have a blind placed but I only can communicate from my Activity to my Service. Whats the quickest and easiest way I can communicate to my Activity from my Service?

p.s the activity I want to contact is not always opened. I want to contact it only when its opened

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be through broadcasts.  In your service you can send out a broadcast as follows:

```
    Intent myBroadcast = new Intent(MYCONSTANT);
    myBroadcast.putExtra("data", "This is a message");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(myBroadcast);
```

Then in the activity you would have a listener as follows:

```
    // initialize in constructor
    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new MyReceiver();

    // in onCreate, register the receiver
    this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(Service.MYCONSTANT));

    // then have a class to receive the broadcast
    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //do stuff          
        }
}
```

There are other ways to register the receiver but I find this way to be the easiest.

Comment: After a little tinkering with this it worked perfectly thanks